# Просмотр настроек postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Как посмотреть настройки *postgresql*, заданные с помощью команды SET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью команды [show](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/sql-show.html) можно увидеть все параметры времени выполнения

```
show all;
```

или какой-то конкретный

```
show time zone;
```

Но команда отображает и параметры установленные вызовом команды `SET`, и установленные по умолчанию, и определённые в конфигурации. Если же нужны только настройки установленные в текущей сессии, можно воспользоваться запросом:

```
select name, setting from pg_settings where source = 'session';
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь..